# Finding the smallest, largest, and middle values in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I did with this code. Is it correct way? I want to sort the numbers in ascending order. Is there better way for this?

```
import java.lang.Math;
public class Numbers
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int a=1;
    int b=2;
    int c=3;

    if (a<b && a<c)
      System.out.println("Smallest: a");
    else if (a>b && a>c)
      System.out.println("Biggest: a");
    else if (a>b && a<c)
      System.out.println("Mid: a");
    else if (a<b && a>c)
      System.out.println("Mid: a");
    if (b<c && b<a)
      System.out.println("Smallest: b");
    else if (b>c && b>a)
      System.out.println("Biggest: b");
    else if (b>c && b<a)
      System.out.println("Mid: b");
    else if (b<c && b>a)
      System.out.println("Mid: b");
    if (c<a && c<b)
      System.out.println("Smallest: c");
    else if (c>a && c>b)
      System.out.println("Biggest: c");
    else if (c>a && c<b)
      System.out.println("Mid: c");
    else if (c<a && c>b)
      System.out.println("Mid: c");
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to array the numbers"?

Comment: You literally do nothing with Arrays in this question. What do you mean you want to array them?

Comment: Do you just want to get the values or the "name" as well? If it is only the values you're interested in then just create an array and sort (any tutorial or the documentation section on arrays should help here). It you want the names as well you could create an object that contains name and number, create an array/list of those and sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Steve's answer (I assume you are new to Java and need a more complete example):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Numbers
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int a=3;
    int b=2;
    int c=1;
    int[] numbers = {a,b,c};
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println("The highest number is "+numbers[2]);
    System.out.println("The middle number is "+numbers[1]);
    System.out.println("The lowest number is "+numbers[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the three numbers in an array and then do

```
Arrays.sort(numbers);

/* numbers[0] will contain your minimum
 * numbers[1] will contain the middle value
 * numbers[2] will contain your maximum
 */
```

That's all!

Answer (score 1):

In general it would be best to use a loop and a array for this type of thing that way if you have more than 3 numbers it will still work. Also you wont have to type nearly as much. Try something like this for finding the smallest number.

```
MyArray = new int[3];

MyArray[0] = 1;
MyArray[1] = 2;
MyArray[2] = 3;

int temp = a;

for (int i = 0; i < (number of numbers to check in this case 3); i++){
    if (MyArray[i] < temp){
        temp = MyArray[i];
    }
}

System.out.println("Smallest number is: " + temp);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortingIntegers {

    public static void main (String[] args){
         int num1;
         int num2;
         int num3;
         int largerstNum;
         int smallestNum;
         int middleNum;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the First Integer");
        num1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Pleas enter the Second Integer");
        num2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the third Integer");
        num3 = sc.nextInt();

        if (num1 > num2){
            if (num1 > num3){
                largerstNum = num1;
                if (num2 > num3){
                    middleNum = num2;
                    smallestNum = num3;
                }else {
                    middleNum = num3;
                    smallestNum = num2;
                }
            }
        }else {
            if (num1 > num3){
                middleNum = num1;
                if (num2 > num3){
                    largerstNum = num2;
                    smallestNum = num3;
                }else {
                    largerstNum = num3;
                    smallestNum = num2;

                }
            }else {
                smallestNum =num1;
                if (num2 > num3){
                    largerstNum = num2;
                    middleNum = num3;
                }else {
                    largerstNum = num3;
                    middleNum = num2;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Highest Number is : " + largerstNum);
            System.out.println("Smallest Number is : " + smallestNum);
            System.out.println("Middle Number is : " + middleNum);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to support/explain your code.